# "full join" method for lists

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Lets say we have a two lists `Seq[A]` and `Seq[B]` of certain objects and want to join them on a certain condition `(A, B) => Boolean`. It might be like for one element from the first list there are several matching elements from the second one. If speaking about `full join`, we mean we want to know also for which elements for both list there is no corresponding pair.

So the signature would be:

```
def fullJoin[A, B](left: Seq[A], right: Seq[B], joinCondition: (A, B) => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[B], Seq[(A, B)])
```

Or if we take advantage of Cats' [`Ior`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Ior.scala) type:

```
def fullJoin[A, B](left: Seq[A], right: Seq[B], joinCondition: (A, B) => Boolean): Seq[Ior[A, B]]
```

The example:

```
scala> fullJoin[Int, Int](List(1,2), List(3,4,4), {_ * 2 == _ })
res4: (Seq[Int], Seq[Int], Seq[(Int, Int)]) = (List(1),List(3),List((2,4), (2,4)))
```

The idea is exactly the same as the idea of joining tables in SQL.

The question is whether there are any similar utility methods in the standard library. If not, let's discuss an elegant solution - at first, with performance not being a problem (a quadratic complexity is fine, as for Nested Loop).

Comment: Any chance of being more restrictive about the join condition? If it can be any function, then I don't see any hope of doing better than quadratic complexity, and your posted answer seems fine. But if, for instance, you could narrow it down to an equality join in some way, that opens up possibilities. For instance, require functions `f1: A => C`, `f2: B => C` and join on `f1(a) == f2(b)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that leverages built-in scala library functionality to be a bit more concise:

```
def fullJoin[A, B](left: Seq[A], right: Seq[B], joinCondition: (A, B) => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[B], Seq[(A, B)]) = {
  val matched = for (a <- left; b <- right if joinCondition(a, b)) yield (a, b)
  val matchedLeft = matched.map(_._1).toSet
  val matchedRight = matched.map(_._2).toSet
  (left.filterNot(matchedLeft.contains), right.filterNot(matchedRight.contains), matched)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the full join problem can be solved in terms of left join. Not really optimised, but here is my solution:

```
  def fullJoin[A, B](left: Seq[A], right: Seq[B], joinCondition: (A, B) => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[B], Seq[(A, B)]) = {
    val (notJoinedLeft, joined) = leftJoin(left, right, joinCondition)
    val (notJoinedRight, _)     = leftJoin(right, left, (b: B, a: A) => joinCondition(a, b))
    (notJoinedLeft, notJoinedRight, joined)
  }

  def leftJoin[A, B](left: Seq[A], right: Seq[B], joinCondition: (A, B) => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[(A, B)]) = {
    val matchingResult: Seq[Either[A, Seq[(A, B)]]] = for {
      a <- left
    } yield {
      right.filter(joinCondition.curried(a)) match {
        case Seq()             => Left(a)
        case matchedBs: Seq[B] => Right(matchedBs.map((a, _)))
      }
    }
    val (notMatched: Seq[A], matched: Seq[Seq[(A, B)]]) = partition(matchingResult)
    (notMatched, matched.flatten)
  }

  def partition[A, B](list: Seq[Either[A, B]]): (Seq[A], Seq[B]) = {
    val (lefts, rights) = list.partition(_.isLeft)
    (lefts.map(_.left.get), rights.map(_.right.get))
  }
```